# Hazelcast’s HTTP-based health check behaviour

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-cloud

We have enabled Hazelcast’s HTTP-based health check implementation which provides basic information about your cluster and member on the
node which it is launched.

i.e `http://<member’s host IP>:5701/hazelcast/health`

and getting output as below:

```
Hazelcast::NodeState=ACTIVE
Hazelcast::ClusterState=ACTIVE
Hazelcast::ClusterSafe=TRUE
Hazelcast::MigrationQueueSize=0
Hazelcast::ClusterSize=5
```

Our cluster size is 5 but sometimes monitor reports size 3 or 4 or 2.

Can someone explain on which parameters clustersize is determined means how hazelcast member failure detection works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the clustersize is not steady  it mean nodes could be dropping from the cluster. this could be due to network issue or nodes running out of resources.
Hazelcast failure detection is explained along  with how to select and fine tune detection rules here [Here - Reference Manual](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.3/manual/html-single/index.html#failure-detector-configuration)